# Passing ampersands in Javascript through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I am making an AJAX call with JQuery to a .Net application.  The value that is being passed sometimes to my ajax call is &.

```
var searchValue = '&';
var url = "method=searchvariables&searchvalue="+searchValue;

url += "&position=1";
```

On the .NET side, the searchVale is always null.

How do I pass in the ampersand so it gets recognized by the .Net code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some characters have special meaning in URIs, use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) if you want to use them as data.

Comment: THanks that worked.  And .net handles the decoding too.  (I'd vote for this answer but I don't have enough reputation points).

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage jQuery to build the query string by passing a `data` object. That will take care of `encodeURIComponent` for you

```
$.ajax(URL, {
    data: {
        method : searchvariables,
        searchvalue : searchValue,
        position : 1
    }
});
```